# How to make numpy.argmax return all occurrences of the maximum?

Tags: python, numpy, max

I'm trying to find a function that returns *all* occurrences of the maximum in a given list.

[`numpy.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) however only returns the first occurrence that it finds. For instance:

```
from numpy import argmax

list = [7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
winner = argmax(list)

print winner
```

gives only index `0`. But I want it to give all indices: `0, 3, 5`.

Answer (score 122):

As documentation of `np.argmax` says: *"In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned."*, so you will need another strategy.

One option you have is using `np.argwhere` in combination with `np.amax`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> listy = [7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6]
>>> winner = np.argwhere(listy == np.amax(listy))
>>> print(winner)
 [[0]
  [3]
  [5]]
>>> print(winner.flatten().tolist()) # if you want it as a list
[0, 3, 5]
```

Comment: it's easy to get confused by the `a` in `amax`: it stands for `array`, not `arg`.  one might be better off using `max` (an alias for `amax`) than `amax` itself.

Answer (score 17):

It is even easier, when compared to other answers, if you use [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> your_list = np.asarray([7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6])
>>> winners = np.flatnonzero(your_list == np.max(your_list))
>>> winners
array([0, 3, 5])
```

If you want a list:

```
>>> winners.tolist()
[0, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 9):

In case it matters, the following algorithm runs in O(n) instead of O(2n) (i.e., using `np.argmax` and then `np.argwhere`):

```
def allmax(a):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return []
    all_ = [0]
    max_ = a[0]
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        if a[i] > max_:
            all_ = [i]
            max_ = a[i]
        elif a[i] == max_:
            all_.append(i)
    return all_
```

Comment: I am using similar method in one of my projects. But it seems to have been taking more time than `np.where(a == np.amax(a))[0]`. Any idea?

Comment: Hey there, mathematically O(n) is identical to O(2n) because of how big O notation is defined. Def: f(N) = O(g(N)) if f(N)/g(N) approaches 0 when N approaches infinity. Clearly, any function f such that f(N) = O(N) is also such that f(N) = O(2N) because f(N)/N → 0 ⇔ f(N)/(2N) → 0. TLDR; Consider saying "twice as fast" instead of O(2N) which is identical to O(N).

Answer (score -4):

Much simpler...

list[list == np.max(list)]

Comment: Yes, but using argwhere returns the indices of the occurrences of the maximum, which is what @Marieke_W asked for

Comment: Not an answer to this question, and computationally inferior.