# Get all column indices of equal to max and use them to index another array: numpy vs sparse csr_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Following the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568612/how-to-make-numpy-argmax-return-all-occurrences-of-the-maximum), I am able to find the column indices of a 2D numpy array and get back an array of column indices of all occurrences of the max value.

But now I want to do the same thing but on a sparse csr_matrix.

```
x = np.array([[0,0,1,0,0,0,2],[0,0,0,4,0,0,0],[0,9,1,0,0,0,2],[0,0,1,0,0,9,2]])
max_col_inds = np.argwhere(x == np.max(x))[:,1]
# array([1, 5], dtype=int64)
```

Then I want to get the 1st and 5th elements of a 1D array using that result:

```
words[max_col_inds]
```

If `x` is a 2D numpy array and `words` is a 1D numpy array, this works.

But now if I replace `x` with a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix, I get this on the call to `np.argwhere()`:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: `np.where` does not work with sparse. There is a similar `x.nonzero` (check the docs)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't replicate your error. Perhaps make sure scipy.sparse.csr_matrix is being called correctly, since you refer to it incorrectly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [804]: x = np.array([[0,0,1,0,0,0,2],[0,0,0,4,0,0,0],[0,9,1,0,0,0,2],[0,0,1,0,0,9,2]])
In [805]: np.max(x)
Out[805]: 9
In [806]: np.where(x == 9)
Out[806]: (array([2, 3], dtype=int32), array([1, 5], dtype=int32))
```

`argwhere` is just `np.transpose(np.where(...))`; that is, converts the tuple into a 2d array and transposes it:

```
In [807]: np.argwhere(x ==9)
Out[807]: 
array([[2, 1],
       [3, 5]], dtype=int32)
```

Doing the same thing with sparse

```
In [808]: xM = sparse.csr_matrix(x)
In [809]: xM == 9
Out[809]: 
<4x7 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

`np.where` is the samething as `np.nonzero`:

```
In [810]: (xM==9).nonzero()
Out[810]: (array([2, 3], dtype=int32), array([1, 5], dtype=int32))
In [811]: np.transpose((xM==9).nonzero())
Out[811]: 
array([[2, 1],
       [3, 5]], dtype=int32)
```

Actually in the current `numpy` `argwhere` works with sparse.  That's because `np.nonzero` delegates to the matrix method:

```
In [813]: np.argwhere(xM==9)
Out[813]: 
array([[2, 1],
       [3, 5]], dtype=int32)
```