# Numpy finding max of function + array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I got these two functions:

```
mom=-1/2*q*x**2+1/2*q*len*x
quer=-q*x+1/2*q*len
```

where `x` is an array defined with numpy:

```
x=7
q=10
anzahl = 100
x=np.linspace(0, len, anzahl)
```

I am trying to get the `MAX` of 'mom' & 'quer" which I get with:

```
max(mom) & min(mom)
```

But now I'm trying to get the 'x' value where `mom` is `MAX / MIN`

I tried `print (x.index(max(mom))` but I think this code doesn't connect the two functions in the right way.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find the max index, try to use np.argmax(mom)!
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

In case of more max points, and all needed:
[How to make numpy.argmax return all occurrences of the maximum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568612/how-to-make-numpy-argmax-return-all-occurrences-of-the-maximum)

Comment: perfect, that was the one I was looking for. What if there are 2 MIN / MAX values - in the docs there is only the case where 1 extreme is found: >>> np.argmax(b)  # Only the first occurrence is returned.

Comment: If you need all the occurences, you can follow the strategy mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568612/how-to-make-numpy-argmax-return-all-occurrences-of-the-maximum

Comment: @LosKayos is this what you were looking for?

Comment: yes sir. thank you!

Comment: Can you mark it as solved then please? Thanks :)

Comment: done :)! Thank you again!