# Does np.argmax return the first maximal?

Tags: python, numpy, argmax

Does `np.argmax` return the index of the **first** maximal element always?

Let `a = np.array([1, 3, -7, ...])` be a 1D-array with several maximal elements, say at indices `10`, `20` and `30`. Numpy seems to return systematically `10` instead of `20` or `30`, but I could not find information about this behavior in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), and I could not find the implementation details in the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.23.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1127-L1216). Does anybody know?

Comment: In `Notes` in the documentation it says "In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned.". Isn't this what you're looking for?

Comment: If you need to find all occurrences of the maximum, you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17568803/15032126)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is actually explicited in the [`numpy.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) documentation:

> **Notes**
>
> In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices
> corresponding to the first occurrence are returned.

Answer (score 0):

yes it only outputs the first occurrence but you can use np.argsort to get n top maximum:

```
np.argsort(your_array)[-n:] #the top n indexes
```

i.e.:

```
n=2
a = np.array([1,2,3,3,-1])
np.argsort(a)[-n:]
>array([2, 3], dtype=int64) #elements at index 2 and 3 in array a (3, 3) have the top max values
```